# I'm trying to get the values of the selected checkboxes in Sharepoint and store them in an array and pass it to POST request

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery

I have tried the following code. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I have multiple checkboxes in my sharepoint form. Can somebody help me with this?

$(function () {

```
        var checkedAttr = [];
        $("input:checkbox[name=CheckboxFieldName]:checked").each(function(){
            checkedAttr.push($(this).val());
        });

 $('#CheckboxFieldName :checkbox').change(function() 
        {

          var item = {
                    "Mainr": checkedAttr,
                     "date": "",
                    "Number": "",
                     "arcft": ""
                      }

           $.ajax({
              url: "urlname",
              type: "POST",
              contentType: "application/json",
              data: JSON.stringify(item),
              dataType: "json",

                  success: function (data) {
                  .......
                   },
                  error: function (data) {
                   ....
                 }
        }
```

})

Comment: Can you also provide your checkbox html

Comment: Actually it's a sharepoint form and there's no html as such. I'm retrieving the fields on the sharepoint form by creating a web part.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as below. It says whenever checkbox is clicked and it is checked then it will add value to array.

```
    $("input:checkbox[name=CheckboxFieldName]").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    checkedAttr.push($(this).val());
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the jQuery code below to get the values of selected checkboxes and put the values into an array.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var checkedAttr = [];
    $("input:checkbox[id^='CheckboxFieldName']:checked").each(function(){
        checkedAttr.push($(this).next().text());
    });
    console.log(checkedAttr.toString());
})
</script>
```

[image]